# Magento2: Product Stock Bulk Update API

Tags: magento2, product, api, stock, inventory

I'm looking for the bulk variant of the product stock update API

```
/rest/default/V1/products/{productSku}/stockItems/{itemId}
```

**Objective:**
I want to update quantities of multiple products in one API call

**What I've tried**

I checked the Magento2 guides on bulk APIs and came across this [Bulk endpoints | Magento 2 Developer Documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/bulk-endpoints.html#routes) and based on the info from there updated the above link to this

```
PUT rest/async/bulk/V1/products/byProductSku/stockItems/byItemId
```

and this is the body

```
[
    {
        "productSku": "Test-Product",
        "stockItem": {
            "itemId": 32,
            "qty": 338,
            "is_in_stock": true,
            "use_config_manage_stock": false
        }
    }
]
```

But this isn't working, I'm getting the error

```
{
    "message": "Internal Error. Details are available in the Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-..."
}
```

My two main concerns are whether there is an API I can use that already does this, or if my approach mentioned above is possible and I need to change something to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endpoint you added in your post works properly for me :| I am not sure which is the problem on your environment, but **I suggest you check the log files, surely there must be something in there. And also would be a good idea to verify that your RabbitMQ connection is correctly configured and works properly. (the async.operations.all queue is processed only via *amqp* connection.)**

I also found that you can update the stocks by using the endpoint (useful for MSI especially):
`POST /rest/default/async/bulk/V1/inventory/source-items`
with the following payload:

```
[
 {
  "sourceItems": [
    {
      "sku": "WSH12-29-Red",
      "source_code": "default",
      "quantity": 111,
      "status": 1
    },
     {
      "sku": "MH01-XS-Black",
      "source_code": "default",
      "quantity": 222,
      "status": 1
    }
   ]
  }
]
```

(Redoc https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.2-admin/tag/inventorysource-items/#operation/inventoryApiSourceItemsSaveV1ExecutePost)

Comment: The inventory API works, thanks!

Comment: you are most welcome! :)